# Installing Wix Toolset "Key not valid for use in specified state"

Tags: wix

I need to install the WIX toolset to install the EclipseSCADA msi.

When trying to install WIX v3.8 or 3.9 I get "Key not valid for use in specified state" and the installation fails.

I'm using Windows 8 and I do not have a copy Visual Studio installed.

Am I doing something wrong?

Cheers,

Dafydd

Answer (score 0):

I was advised by the Wixtoolset triage team to try uninstalling Windows hotfix KB2918614.  This worked.